# imgNotes mousewheel scroll change

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming

I used this plugin https://github.com/waynegm/imgNotes in my project.

In this project when mouse wheel rolling down , it is zooming to image but I want to change this.

I want do it like google maps  when I roll mouse wheel to up , it will zoom in to image and rool mousewheel down it will zoom out

Comment: Please add your code to your question

Comment: I don't know where is changable area, so I used imgNotes plugin and imgviewer it's zoom in zoom out roller are  working wrongly, How can I change scale up to down mouse roller like google maps

Comment: You should try to do it yourself. If you cannot get it working, explain what you tried to do and then ask for help. We should not post questions that are basically "Please write this program for me."

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in `imgViewer.min.js` 
Make `f.options.zoom -= b * f.options.zoomStep, f.update()` to `f.options.zoom += b * f.options.zoomStep, f.update()`